# Python Injection - is there such a thing?

Tags: python, code-injection

I've been doing some penetration testing on my own site and have been doing a lot of research on common vulnerabilities.

SQL injection comes up a lot but I was wondering, could there possibly be such a thing as python injection? Say for example that a web form submitted a value that was entered in a dictionary in some python backend app. Would it be possible that if that input wasn't handled correctly that python code could be injected and executed in the app?

Is there a way to easily and harmlessly test for this vulnerability - if it is indeed a potential vulnerability? I can't seem to find many web resources on this topic.

Comment: Python injection? Sure, if you have `eval()` in your code.

Comment: Or  if you unpickle objects from a non-trusted source.

Comment: If the application uses `eval()` on arbitrary string input someone could potentially input `"__import__('subprocess').call(['rm', '-rf', '--no-preserve-root'])"` which could have some "unintended" side effects.

Comment: or running os.system function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on what you *do* with the input from the webform.  In normal use the form gets encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `json` -- Both formats which *can* be deserialized into a python dictionary completely safely.  Of course, they *could* be deserialized in unsafe ways too -- Make sure that you use libraries that are dedicated to handling this properly (e.g. `urlparse` or `json`).

From there, whether the input is safe depends entirely on what the application does with it.  (e.g. it is *not* safe if the application uses `eval` with input based on the decoded dict).

As for automated testing for this -- I don't know of any way to accomplish this, but these problems are generally pretty easy to mitigate by just following normal best-practices (don't `eval` code you don't trust, etc. etc.)